# Does your storage carry over difficulties?

Tags: borderlands-2

Does the bank keep the items you have in it for a specific character even if you switch difficulties, or does the items you've collected on a certain difficulty of the game only work on that level of play?

Comment: I may be remembering this wrong, but I think when I levelled to TVHM then UVHM, it kept not only the bank items, but everything in your inventory.

Comment: IF you are happy with an answer, remember to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

The bank items are per character no matter what difficulty you are on.  However, you will not have access to it for a while until you reach the point where you can get to the bank.

Comment: To add to this, the items you ended the game with are also carried over to use immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use items regardless of which difficulty you looted them on and the difficulty you switched to in Borderlands 2 (or BL1 for that matter).